# Using Docker in local development

Tags: java, maven, docker

I’m learning how to use Docker in my java/spring based applications.

After quick research and reading few tutorials I have doubts about using Docker in daily development. I’m not talking about CI or production environments, only locally.

Normally I run e.g. embedded Tomcat using mvn (run goal). With docker approach I need to package application, rebuild container and then restart it (David Gageot at DockerCon16 confirmed that). At first sight it will take more time. Each time the change is made, the new image should be built.

Where is advantage in using Docker localy? Of course I know that application runs „in the same environment as in production”.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You have raised a very valid point and in your scenario there indeed is a time penalty.  The big advantages come when *"it works on my machine"* it should work nicely on the staging, QA Testing and production environments regardless of operating system.

I use docker locally for my java spring development but mostly for quickly and consistently bringing up databases and messaging systems which the build / project depends on.  For example, I have an application which depends on MongoDB, MySQL, ElasticSearch and RabbitMQ.  I have docker images for each of these and a docker compose file to bring them all up using a single [docker-compose up](https://docs.docker.com/compose/reference/up/) command.  This means I don't have to install these manually on my laptop and it's defo a nicer solution when you move to another project which has different dependant databases, middleware, etc.  Before as I moved from projects to projects I had to manually stop and start these databases as they were taking up so much memory running all the time.

Docker also has advantages in a local environment if you have an acceptance test suite (which again depends on external things like databases etc) in your build - again it's main advantages are again down to consistency i.e. if it runs locally it should run as part of your Jenkins build.

My advice will be, there are defo advantages to docker e.g. our builds are so much more reliable and configurable these days but only use it where it makes sense - Docker is no silver bullet.  E.g. you may decide it's much nicer to run Tomcat in Eclipse as debugging is so much easier (no need for a remote debugging session).